# using Log4j2 in servlet 3.0

Tags: java, log4j2, servlet-3.0

I am using Log4j2 for logging purpose in my web application.
If I create any simple java class and call my logger , it works perfectly fine and print the logs in a file. However if I do the same in servlet class, it is not working.
As specified in the documentation I have not configured anything related to log4j2 in web.xml.

Code for Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>SampleWebApp</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>Welcome.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Logging code in Servlet class:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final Logger log=LogManager.getLogger(MyServlet.class);
```

I have not explicitly placed log4j2.xml file in WEB-INF folder ,since I have added this file in classpath , its automatically added in WEB-INF/classes after I build the project.

Am I missing some configurations?

Line of Code :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        log.error("i am inside servlet");
        /*response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());*/
        System.out.println("GET called");

    }
```

log4j2.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>
      <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="MyFile" filename="C:/Users/jasleen_kathuria/Documents/logs/info.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
      </Appenders>
<Loggers>
<logger name="MyServlet" level="TRACE">
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
    </logger>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: "it's not working" is still the best error description on SA... can you at least specify what the error is you're getting? A compiler error, runtime error or can the logger not access the log file, can't you find the log file on the server, what is it? :)

Comment: This is strange but I am not getting any error ! Its just that the logs are not getting generated.

Comment: Is MyServlet class in a package, if so you have to put the _full name_ in the logger config.

Comment: My Servlet class is placed directly under src folder.I have also tried giving a different name to logger in the config file like "myLogger" and using it in MyServlet.java . I am a newbie and trying to learn Java, I have checked all the log files for tomcat , no error is being logged anywhere.

Comment: What about the console logger do you see your log messages anywhere in the tomcat log files (try at "TOMCAT_HOME/logs/")!? if not try a simple console debug message in your method without the logger and see if you can find that message first.

Answer (score 0):

You should say at least how you build/deploy your web-app, on which servlet container, and how you *add things* to classpath.

All the same, the main problem is probably the fact that you are not adding log4j2 jar in WEB-INF/lib and or it's configuration in WEB-INF/classes.

When you call your simple java class , you are relying to a different classpath from your web-app.

Make sure that log4j2.jar is deployed, for example you can build the war unzip it and see what it contains.

Comment: Sorry to miss these details .I am using Tomcat 8.5 and I have placed the 2 main jar files for log4j2 (core and api) in the WEB-INF/lib folder and the configuration file is also present in WEB-INF/classes folder. I export my project as a WAR file and place it in the Tomcat web-apps folder.

Comment: Please, post at least the actual error (if any) and show a line of code using  the logger which does not work..

Comment: I am calling my servlet through an ajax call . The ajax call is successful but the logging code is neither executed nor it gives any compile or run time error.

Comment: What we need to help you is: a fragment of code of servlet using the logger, the log4j2 config , and the exact error you get (a stack trace, no error but no logging etc...), please add all useful information not as a reply but to the question, so other may help without reading all comments.

Answer (score 0):

Well it got resolved after I restarted my Tomcat and cleared my Browser cache. I am able to see the logs being printed now.